# Post to Facebook photos with preview using feed or share dialog

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to post to user photos on Facebook using Feed or Share dialog but instead of going to a link it should open the image posted. I have seen it happening in mobile apps where you can just share your scores and it is posted as an images added to your photos but I can't find a similar example on web.

What I want to achieve is user create a meme or image.
Click on share.
Previews the image in a dialog 
and post as an image to facebook, Without having to granting permissions or posting from backend.

Please tell me if there is a way to do so